# encountered "cleanup:" in a Foundation code sample in Xcode. What is this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, label, goto

so in some sample code from this upcoming [Core Audio Book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/audio/9780321636973) i've encountered an unfamiliar symbol

```
cleanup:
```

which is used before some dispose(myStuff) functions are called. It's not preceded by an '@' or a '#'. Seems you can type any word, followed by a colon, and it will act like a comment?

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        NSLog(@"i am code.");

    cleanup:    
    foop:
    lol:

        NSLog(@"even more code.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a comment. It's a label specifying a location for `goto`.

E.g.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        printf("Is this an infinite loop?\n");
        goto endLabel;
    }

    endLabel:    

    printf("No.");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Is this an infinite loop?
No.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a label, to be used in a `goto` statement.